# Logical operator precedence in Java

Tags: java

I'm not happy about this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.22 . It clearly states the following:

> "Each operator is commutative if the operand expressions have no side effects."

and

> "These operators have different precedence, with & having the highest precedence and | the lowest precedence".

How come the JVM doesn't comply to it's own rules. Take for instance the following example.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    boolean bool = isTrue1() | isFalse1() & isFalse2() ;
    System.out.println("Result : " + bool);
}

public static boolean isFalse1() {
    System.out.println("1 : " + false);
    return false ;
}
public static boolean isFalse2() {
    System.out.println("2 : " + false);
    return false ;
}
public static boolean isTrue1() {
    System.out.println("3 : " + true);
    return true ;
}
```

The result is:

```
3 : true
1 : false
2 : false
Result : true
```

While the actual result should be, according to the fact that & operators are evaluated before | operators:

```
1 : false
2 : false
3 : true
Result : true
```

Some explanation would be nice as to why this isn't correctly implemented. Even when adding parentheses around the second part, the correct precedence isn't used.

Comment: What's the issue?  Your results match up, they are just out of order.

Comment: These are not logical operators but bit operators.

Comment: According to the official java specification, they are called both logical operators and bitwise operators depending on the data surrounding them. Meanwhile && and || are called Conditional-And/Conditional-Or operators. This doesn't even matter for the question how you call them. I suggest you take a look at the linked specification.

Comment: @trevor-e The issue is, that when my code has side effects (which I demonstrated with a simple sout call here), I can't depend on the official java specification to be correct. Which I'm seeking an explanation for.

Comment: @user2890248 "Operator precedence" has to do with how expressions are interpreted; it simply means that `a | b & c` is equivalent to `a | (b & c)` and not `(a | b) & c`.  It has nothing to do with the order in which the parts are evaluated at runtime.  Unfortunately, I was going to point to you a resource that explains "operator precedence", but the first sentence of the Wikipedia page actually confuses the issue.  I may have to complain about that.

Comment: @user2890248 They are both. However, `||` and `&&` are short-circuiting, which `|` and `&` are not.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> "These operators have different precedence, with & having the highest
>   precedence and | the lowest precedence".

Just because they have higher precedence, doesn't mean their operands will be evaluated first.

This

```
boolean bool = isTrue1() | isFalse1() & isFalse2() ;
```

becomes equivalent to

```
boolean bool = isTrue1() | ( isFalse1() & isFalse2() ) ;
```

That's all precedence is.

As the Java Language Specification says, [operator operands are evaluated left to right.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.7)

> The Java programming language guarantees that the operands of
>   operators appear to be evaluated in a specific evaluation order,
>   namely, from left to right.

Answer (score 3):

The & has higher precedence than | but in your case, evaluating this:

```
boolean bool = isTrue1() | isFalse1() & isFalse2()
```

is the same as evaluating this:

```
  boolean bool = (isTrue1()) | (isFalse1() & isFalse2())
```

Which means, the two sides of the | expression are the same precedence. So java will evaluate them in the left-to-right order in that case.

First it will call isTrue1(), being the first on the left and then the second paranthesis, again evaluating what is inside it in the left-to-right order: isFalse1() and then isFalse2().

Answer (score 1):

The order of method evaluation isn't necessarily going to match up with the operator precedence; the side effects of each method appear in the order in which you called the method, then their results are evaluated to produce your final print statement.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing here is a **bitwise** combination and not a logic operation. So Java follows the left-to-right order as one would expect.

If you actually use **logical** operations (replace | with || and & with &&), the result becomes:

```
1 : true
Result : true
```

Comment: This isn't the most important difference, the important thing is that `||` and `&&` are *short circuiting*.

Answer (score -2):

Java will call all the functions before comparing the results, since you're using binary comparators (& and |) instead of logical comparators (&& and ||)

Comment: All the functions may not be called if the result of the expression is already determined - This is called [short circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation)

Comment: @Gowtham short circuit evaluation is not used for `&` and `|`.  It's used only for `&&` and `||`.